# LLVM: Cannot select: intrinsic %llvm.spu.si.sf

Tags: llvm, clang, intrinsics

I am getting this error

```
> clang -std=c99 -c derivative.c -o derivative.a
fatal error: error in backend: Cannot select: intrinsic %llvm.spu.si.sf
```

when I try to compile this simple C program with Clang

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int N = 100;
double H = 0.001;
double PI = 3.14159265;

void derive(double* input, long elements, double* output) {
  for (int i = 1; i < elements - 1; i++) {
    output[i - 1] = (input[i + 1] - input[i - 1])/ (2 * H);
  }
}

int main() {
  double f[N];
  double f_prime[N - 2];

  for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    f[i] = sin(i * 2 * PI / (double)N);
  }

  derive(f, N, f_prime);

  for (int i = 0; i < N - 2; i++) {
    printf("%f  %f\n", i * 2 * PI / (double)N, f_prime[i]);
  }
}
```

I already searched the Internet, but was not (yet) able to find a solution.

When I compile to Bitcode, it compiles but the execution dumps core.

```
> clang -emit-llvm -c derivative.c -o derivative.bc
> lli derivative.bc
lli: BitcodeReader.cpp:283: llvm::Value* llvm::BitcodeReaderValueList::getValueFwdRef(unsigned int, llvm::Type*): Assertion `(Ty == 0 || Ty == V->getType()) && "Type mismatch in value table!"' failed.
0  lli             0x0000000000c6fb02
1  lli             0x0000000000c6ff93
2  libpthread.so.0 0x00007f304d7dbbd0
3  libc.so.6       0x00007f304ca19037 gsignal + 55
4  libc.so.6       0x00007f304ca1c698 abort + 328
5  libc.so.6       0x00007f304ca11e03
6  libc.so.6       0x00007f304ca11eb2
7  lli             0x000000000052eeb0 llvm::BitcodeReaderValueList::getConstantFwdRef(unsigned int, llvm::Type*) + 0
8  lli             0x0000000000538943 llvm::BitcodeReader::ParseFunctionBody(llvm::Function*) + 10275
9  lli             0x000000000053acb1 llvm::BitcodeReader::Materialize(llvm::GlobalValue*, std::string*) + 241
10 lli             0x0000000000535195 llvm::BitcodeReader::MaterializeModule(llvm::Module*, std::string*) + 85
11 lli             0x0000000000c0a82f llvm::Module::MaterializeAllPermanently(std::string*) + 31
12 lli             0x00000000005360fc llvm::ParseBitcodeFile(llvm::MemoryBuffer*, llvm::LLVMContext&, std::string*) + 44
13 lli             0x00000000004f70b7
14 lli             0x00000000004e74f3 main + 339
15 libc.so.6       0x00007f304ca03ea5 __libc_start_main + 245
16 lli             0x00000000004f0f41
Stack dump:
0.  Program arguments: lli derivative.bc 
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Trying `llvm-dis` on the bc-file yields an almost identical core dump.

**EDIT**:
I tried to find the minimal failing example, and it seems, the problem is defining the array size via the constant.

this fails:

```
int main() {
  int N = 100;
  double f[N];
}
```

this works:

```
int main() {
  double f[100];
}
```

**EDIT2**:

Changing `int N = 100` to `const int N = 100` makes the program compile with Clang.
It makes sense that the variable should be `const`, but on the other hand, `gcc -std=c99 -Wall derivative.c -lm` does not complain if it is not `const`.

Comment: Which clang version on which architecture? Can't repeat with XCode 4.6 clang (LLVM3.1 based)

Comment: From `clang -v`:
Ubuntu clang version 3.2-1~exp5ubuntu2 (tags/RELEASE_32/final) (based on LLVM 3.2)
Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix

Comment: My first guess was, I need to explicitly link the math library. Eg. for `gcc` I would use `-lm`. But I could not find any hints when searching for `math.h` issues and Clang.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is ubuntu bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/llvm-3.2/+bug/1131614. Looks like they patched llvm+clang blindly, without understanding what they are doing.

Answer (score 1):

The fatal error message is an indication you have discovered a bug in the compiler. Try reporting the bug at llvm.org/bugs.

Comment: Do you think the compiler is still so alpha that even this simple program cannot be compiled? I'd like to somehow make sure the error is not on my side, before I file a bug report.

Comment: @cpt.jazz Even if you did something wrong in linking, there _is_ a bug in that it shows a bad error message. I think a report is in order if it's (based on) a release version of the compiler.