# LLVM ERROR: Cannot select: intrinsic %llvm.objc.clang.arc.use

Tags: objective-c, clang, llc

I'm getting the next error with [llc](https://llvm.org/docs/CommandGuide/llc.html) when trying to to link some IR files:

```
LLVM ERROR: Cannot select: intrinsic %llvm.objc.clang.arc.use
```

I discovered that if I disabled clang optimization (`O0`) during compilation the error doesn't pop up, but I don't want to do that

I attach a sample of how to reproduce it, just `cd` the 'issue' folder and run the 'issue.sh' to reproduce the error. You must have Xcode (12.x preferred) tu run it

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1j0TvMZI2A7QxRbv_Q7aydtlNYaiTPYBm/view?usp=sharing

This is what the issue.sh contains, that is a reduced version of my real implementation:

```sh
echo "clang..."

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -x objective-c \
-target arm64-apple-ios12.0 \
-fobjc-arc -fmodules \
-S -Os -flto=thin \
-isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS14.1.sdk \
-fembed-bitcode \
-c ${PWD}/GTMSessionFetcher.m \
-o ${PWD}/GTMSessionFetcher.ll

echo "llc..."

${PWD}/llc \
GTMSessionFetcher.ll \
-stats -filetype=obj \
-code-model=small \
-enable-machine-outliner=never \
--mtriple=arm64-apple-ios12.0 \
-o ${PWD}/GTMSessionFetcher.o
```

As I mentioned before, if you change `-Os` for `-O0`, the error disappears, but I do need the size optimization.

The objective-c file that I included is a file from a pod from a Google library

https://github.com/google/gtm-session-fetcher

I found a similar question, but it doesn't have any answer yet
[LLVM Error Cannot select intrinsic %llvm.coro.begin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66228271/llvm-error-cannot-select-intrinsic-llvm-coro-begin)

Answer (score 1):

I thought it was bug, but it wasn't

As Akira pointed me in [LLVM bug report](https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=49717) I was able to fix it by adding an intermediate optimizer `OPT` step with `-objc-arc-contract` flag:

```sh
clang
...

<path to your LLVM tools>/OPT \
<Your IR file> \
-objc-arc-contract \
-o <Output file>

llc
...
```